# Correct way of using logo in HTML5

Tags: html, css, web

What's the valid way of placing logo in a website.

```
<a href="#" class="logo"></a>
```

and CSS

```
a.logo
{
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("images/logo.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

OR

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
```

Comment: I suggest that the second one is better

Comment: I'll use the img tag. Better for the user (who might want to save the logo) or for indexing it in the search engines.

Comment: I second the second suggestion. Also the `a.logo` selector probably doesn't need the `a` part, it can just be `.logo`.

Comment: This is opinion based and opinions such as this aren't allowed on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is definitely better cause there's no content in the `<a>` with the CSS only option.

```
<a href="/">
  <img src="#" alt="Company Name">
</a>
```

If you were going to go with the CSS only option, you'd want to do the following:

```
<a href="/" aria-label="Company Name"></a>
```

or

```
<a href="/">
  <span class="sr-only">Company Name</span>
</a>
```

As far as your CSS is concerned, you would want to do this for the option with the image:

```
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
}
```

If going with one of the non-image options, you'd want to do something like:

```
.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: /* necessary width */;
  height: /* necessary height */;
  background: /* necessary background values */
}
```

edit:
Screen reader only class to visually hide content but make it available to screen readers:

```
/* ie9+ */
.sr-only:not(:focus):not(:active) {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(100%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: What's with the aria-label and sr-only class? Just use an `alt` tag on the anchor element if you're concerned with accessibility.

Comment: Note that [`aria-label` does not work consistently on links](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#practical-support-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby)

Comment: @EdmundReed - alt on an anchor element will do nothing.

Comment: @Alochi, it will be read out by screenreaders, no? Which is presumably the intention of the aria-label tag.

Comment: @EdmundReed - No it won't.

Comment: @EdmundReed you can see, by reading my answer, that the examples for aria-label and sr-only class are IF the OP does not use the recommended example.  Also, the alt attribute is only valid on images, hence it not being used in the examples without images.

Comment: @Alohci is correct in that aria-label won't always be respected by screen readers. Here is a good breakdown of situations where it will run into trouble: https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/a-aria-label/

Answer (score 0):

You have two different options:

**HTML:**

Using a `div` or `a` tags with CSS property `background-image: url("images/logo.png");`
In this this case your logo is raster a raster image (pnh/jpg/gif).

**SVG:**

Using SVG your logo is vector and could be scaled up or down without any loss of resolution, which could be a good solution if you are planning to create a responsive design where the logo size could be different accordingly to the device.

Example of SVG link:
http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lCEux

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want it positioned. The first way you mentioned is difficult because you are positioning it like an element inside (the position will depend on the parent node/element) whatever the parent node/element is.

That being said, I prefer the second method when using anything other than text. You have to realize that when you set the CSS attributes of the `<a>` tag, they are intended to encapsulate text (not an image), so when it gets rendered, you will have to make **(read: )** strange adjustments that you wouldn't otherwise have to make (like setting the `line-height` attribute instead of the `height` attribute in CSS).

**I would go with the 2nd method for sure.**

If it ends up looking funny, make sure you set the `a` tag's `text-decoration` attribute to `none` in your CSS.